# Apache Reverse Proxy With SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy

Is it possbile to reverse proxy to internal server via HTTPS and serve the certificate from the backend server instead of the certificate on the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this cannot be done as it would allow for [man in the middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: I thought that would be the case, just wanted to clarify.
Thanks

Comment: Proxying SSL/TLS from one server to another does not facilitate MITM in itself. Only when the middle/proxy server terminates the SSL connection (by either using the valid certificate or some malicious one) and then redirects that traffic elsewhere is it a MITM. It's actually pretty common to have a load balancer, which can be an Apache server but more commonly Nginx, proxy SSL traffic to terminating servers, as the proxy server can't inspect the traffic if it's not decrypted.

Answer (score 2):

konqi> That's pretty much the reverse proxy configuration I've been using for years, with a rewrite rule instead of proxy directives which did not work well here.

```
RewriteEngine On
# is the virtualhost in the allowed server list ?
RewriteCond %{SERVERNAME} ^(server1|server2|server3|server4)\.domain\.com$
# then redirect to the real server (which the virtualhost name resolves to on the proxy)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [P]
# else block it all
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

Plain and simple.

Comment: Nico57 you seem to know what you are talking about. Can you check my question out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42675604/ssl-parse-server-apache-proxy-pass-provide-a-reverse-proxy-to-parse-server

Answer (score 0):

Found this configuration as followed:

- You have ONE Domain example.com with different subdomains as VHOSTs (one.example.com, two.example.com, ..)
- You have a Wildcard-Certificate for your domain *.example.com
- You need mod_proxy
- with Proxy directives works for different servernames matching *.example.com
- If there are not other webservers behind the proxy, add  without SSL for your domains which are the proxied in the VirtualHost:443 configuration above.

Hot chick! Couldn't believe that this works, but it seems to! Not found any specification to that behaviour, but try yourself.

With kind regards,
~Marcel

P.S: NOT regarding any security doubts here! Please keep in mind that these proxy calls to the "backend" are unsecured and therefore (as like mentioned by Rob) potentially dangerous!